# Infinite Loop in Binary tree

Tags: c++, tree, binary-tree

This is a function for building a binary tree, where the parameters are a list of integers(list) and an empty vector for the tree to be written to(tree).  I'm sure it is a very simple error, but for some reason I am overlooking what is causing this to loop.  Thanks for the help.

```
void buildTree(vector<int> list, vector<int> tree)
{
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++)
    {
    bool placed = false;
    int source = 1;

        while(!placed)
        {
            if(tree[source] == NULL)
            {
                tree[source] = list[i];
                placed = true;
            }
            else if(list[i] < source)
            {
                source = 2*source;
            }

            else if(list[i] > source)
            {
                source = 2*source+1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose `placed` is never becoming `true`.

Comment: I would just like to comment that I enjoy that your code has a `vector` named `list`.

Comment: Don't use STL words such as `list` for your variable names, please. It is confusing.

Comment: You don't ever test `list[i] == source`. Is that intentional?

Comment: The other issue is that your `tree` is passed by value.  When that function returns, the `tree` you passed would not have changed.  Pass the `tree` by reference, not by value.

Comment: Has the idea of debugging your code step by step come to your mind? It is often useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing the value (i.e. `list[i]`) to an *index* (i.e. `source`) rather than using `tree[source]`:

```
else if(list[i] < tree[source])
{
    source = 2*source;
}
else if(list[i] > tree[source])
{
    source = 2*source+1;
}
```

In addition, your program does not specify what happens when `list[i]` is equal to `tree[source]`, which could potentially cause an infinite loop.

Another issue that your program has is that it does not check the size of the `tree` before dereferencing one of its elements by index. This could cause undefined behavior. To address this last issue, add this "catch clause" to your `while` loop:

```
if (source >= tree.size()) {
    cerr << "Tree index exceeds the allocated size. Breaking the loop." << endl;
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume that `list[0]` is 1, and `tree[1]` is not NULL. In this case the while loop will be executed infinitely, because none of the tree `if` conditions is met.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparisons, `list[i] < source` and `list[i] > source` should be `list[i] < tree[source]` and `list[i] > tree[source]`. As of now, you are comparing the value you are trying to insert with the INDEX of the tree vector.

Answer (score 0):

Some problems with your code:

-you are receiving the vectors by value, in all the calls to the function the vectors would be copied, and for this, outside the function you could not access to the written `vector tree` and be paying a performance hit.
-i am assuming you are using an empty tree (if not erase lines `if (tree.size() < source) { tree.resize(source); }`. This is because the size of the vector to represent the tree could not be predicted, depend of the element in list. This could be enhanced by allocating more space that needed to avoid multiple consecutive allocations, ex: allocating `sources * factor` (factor > 1.0) instead of `source` like vector do
-you are comparing the list element with index of `tree`: `else if(list[i] < source)`, this comparative need to with the values.

```
void buildTree(const vector<int>& list, vector<int>& tree) {
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        bool placed = false;
        int source = 1;
        while (!placed) {
            if (tree.size() < source) {
                tree.resize(source);
            }

            if (tree[source - 1] == 0) {
                tree[source - 1] = list[i];
                placed = true;
            } else if (list[i] < tree[source - 1]) {
                source = 2 * source;
            } else if (list[i] > tree[source - 1]) {
                source = 2 * source + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

std::vector<int> tree;
buildTree(std::vector<int>{5, 2, 4, 13, 8, 25, 32}, tree);
```

Answer (score 0):

your Logic seems to be wrong. you are comparing "list item" with "index source".

If you are trying to construct "binary heap", starting with no elements in resultant tree,
might be complex to code.

Instead try copying list to tree, and then adjust the first half elements in tree using
Heapify logic.